# Regex, Word contains x but doesn't start with x

Tags: regex

I'm not sure how to do this. I want a string to contain "end" but not start with end. An example would be the word "ascending". I've tried `^[^(end)]*end.*`, but this finds "end" too.
So how would this be done correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt didn't work because you confused a negated character class (defined with `[^...]`, but able to cover just a single character by definition) with a negative lookahead (defined with `(?!...)`).

Have you written this properly, it would have looked like that:

```
^(?!end).+end.*$
```

... with `+` instead of `*` right after the preceding `.` for obvious reasons. )

Note that more straight-forward attempt - `^.+end.*$` - while looking pretty normal, actually fails on words looking like `endendless` (i.e., when there's an `end` substring in the target string, yet it does start with `end` too).

Also, if you're looking for *words* in the target string, and not just validate it, you should adjust the regex accordingly, using word boundary anchors instead of string anchors like that:

```
\b(?!end)\w+end\w*
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/iC4eP6/1).

Comment: You may want to edit this to account for word boundary at the front end, or post that additionally. This would match "This is the end of  the world as we know it", or "This is the end".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm working with python and iterate through the words, so every string is a word. I tried it with negative lookahead, but I forgot to add .+ Silly me, thanks.

Comment: @user3146659: if every string is a word you don't need a regex at all, you only need to check if the substring from the begining to the third character is not "end".

Comment: You can just call for `index` of "end" substring and drop out if it's either not found or found right at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Yes, using the index is a better way.

Comment: I know regex is a bad choice for this, but it was the first to spring to my mind and the first few examples were fairly easy, so I decided to do it all in the same style.